# Could not load file or assembly 'System.Web.Http 4.0.0 after update from 2012 to 2013

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, odata, visual-studio-2013

I did the upgrade according to. 
http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/mvc-5/how-to-upgrade-an-aspnet-mvc-4-and-web-api-project-to-aspnet-mvc-5-and-web-api-2

I get the error. Does any one else got this error?

> ### Server Error in '/' Application.
>
> Could not load file or assembly 'System.Web.Http, Version=4.0.0.0,
>   Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' or one of its
>   dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not
>   match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)
>   Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of
>   the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more
>   information about the error and where it originated in the code.
>
> Exception Details: System.IO.FileLoadException: Could not load file
>   or assembly 'System.Web.Http, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' or one of its dependencies. The
>   located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly
>   reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)
>
> Source Error:
>
> Line 48:              Line 49:              Line 50:         } Line
>   51:  Line 52:         protected void Application_BeginRequest(object
>   sender, EventArgs e)
>
> Source File: 
>   d:\SM\7.4Test\WebAPIServerV2\ThirdPartyWebAPI\Global.asax.cs    Line: 
>   50
>
> Assembly Load Trace: The following information can be helpful to
>   determine why the assembly 'System.Web.Http, Version=4.0.0.0,
>   Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' could not be loaded.
>
> === Pre-bind state information === LOG: DisplayName = System.Web.Http, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35 
>   (Fully-specified) LOG: Appbase =
>   file:///D:/SM/7.4Test/WebAPIServerV2/ThirdPartyWebAPI/ LOG: Initial
>   PrivatePath = D:\SM\7.4Test\WebAPIServerV2\ThirdPartyWebAPI\bin
>   Calling assembly : ThirdPartyWebAPI, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=null.
>   === LOG: This bind starts in default load context. LOG: Using application configuration file:
>   D:\SM\7.4Test\WebAPIServerV2\ThirdPartyWebAPI\web.config LOG: Using
>   host configuration file:
>   C:\Users\michalc\Documents\IISExpress\config\aspnet.config LOG: Using
>   machine configuration file from
>   C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\config\machine.config.
>   LOG: Post-policy reference: System.Web.Http, Version=4.0.0.0,
>   Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35 LOG: Attempting
>   download of new URL
>   file:///C:/Windows/Microsoft.NET/Framework/v4.0.30319/Temporary
>   ASP.NET Files/root/9184b2ea/c6d4b139/System.Web.Http.DLL. LOG:
>   Attempting download of new URL
>   file:///C:/Windows/Microsoft.NET/Framework/v4.0.30319/Temporary
>   ASP.NET
>   Files/root/9184b2ea/c6d4b139/System.Web.Http/System.Web.Http.DLL. LOG:
>   Attempting download of new URL
>   file:///D:/SM/7.4Test/WebAPIServerV2/ThirdPartyWebAPI/bin/System.Web.Http.DLL.
>   WRN: Comparing the assembly name resulted in the mismatch: Major
>   Version ERR: Failed to complete setup of assembly (hr = 0x80131040).
>   Probing terminated.
>
> Stack Trace:
>
> [FileLoadException: Could not load file or assembly 'System.Web.Http,
>   Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' or
>   one of its dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition
>   does not match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT:
>   0x80131040)]    ThirdPartyWebAPI.WebApiApplication.Application_Start()
>   in d:\SM\7.4Test\WebAPIServerV2\ThirdPartyWebAPI\Global.asax.cs:50
>
> [HttpException (0x80004005): Could not load file or assembly
>   'System.Web.Http, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' or one of its dependencies. The
>   located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly
>   reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)]
>   System.Web.HttpApplicationFactory.EnsureAppStartCalledForIntegratedMode(HttpContext
>   context, HttpApplication app) +9935033
>   System.Web.HttpApplication.RegisterEventSubscriptionsWithIIS(IntPtr
>   appContext, HttpContext context, MethodInfo[] handlers) +118
>   System.Web.HttpApplication.InitSpecial(HttpApplicationState state,
>   MethodInfo[] handlers, IntPtr appContext, HttpContext context) +172
>   System.Web.HttpApplicationFactory.GetSpecialApplicationInstance(IntPtr
>   appContext, HttpContext context) +336
>   System.Web.Hosting.PipelineRuntime.InitializeApplication(IntPtr
>   appContext) +296
>
> [HttpException (0x80004005): Could not load file or assembly
>   'System.Web.Http, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' or one of its dependencies. The
>   located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly
>   reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)]
>   System.Web.HttpRuntime.FirstRequestInit(HttpContext context) +9913572 
>   System.Web.HttpRuntime.EnsureFirstRequestInit(HttpContext context)
>   +101    System.Web.HttpRuntime.ProcessRequestNotificationPrivate(IIS7WorkerRequest
>   wr, HttpContext context) +254

---

Version Information: Microsoft .NET Framework Version:4.0.30319; ASP.NET Version:4.0.30319.18408

Comment: have you tried re-adding the reference to 'System.Web.Http'

Answer (score 310):

I fixed this by [reinstalling the NuGet package](http://docs.nuget.org/docs/workflows/reinstalling-packages), which corrects broken dependencies. From the package manager, run:

```
Update-Package Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi -reinstall
```

Comment: Running the web app locally was ok for me (F5), but when deploying to remote server (with WebDeploy) the assemblies were not copied to the server. I was not sure if the assemblies should've been copied or not. Anyway, after running this command all the required assemblies were marked with copy-local=true and after deploying the app started working properly

Comment: Just to add a more balanced picture - this did not resolve the problem for me.

Comment: Be sure to add the needed update to any dependent projects such as tests, etc.

Comment: I did this and it made too many changes, but I did notice it adjusted the binding redirects in the web.config, I discarded all the other changes it made and this worked for me.

Comment: now I am getting a new error: the new version is Version=5.2.3.0 and it expects Version=4.0.0.0

Comment: This didn't work for me but sent me down a rabbit hole that did lead to a solution.  Long story short... I had to delete all Microsoft.AspNet.* from references as well as packages.config and then I was able to right click on project, Manage NuGet packages, and then install "Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi V4.0.20710" (version required for my solution) and then everything compiled and ran.

Comment: for me this worked >> Update-Package Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Client -reinstall

Comment: it's time to mark this as an answer after 6 years. worked like a charm.

Answer (score 86):

**To resolve the Could not load file or assembly 'System.Web.Http' error use NuGet to install the Web API 2.1 WebHost.**

In solution explorer in the references right click and select manage nuget packages. (if not there install nuget)

[image]

In the manage NuGet Packages window on the left side click online then in top right search for Web Host and install Microsoft ASP.NET Web API 2.1 Web Host. (Once installed the install button will change to a green check)

After that the project will reload and when it's build again the error will be resolved and the project will debug and run. The error will be gone and you may be 'The resource cannot be found. Just append the url ( ex from  localhost:52088/ to localhost:52088api/products )

Your question was good and helped me.

Hope this answer helps!

Comment: Thanks Catto, It healped me a lot.

Answer (score 66):

You need to add assembly redirects:

```
<configuration>

   ....

   <runtime>
      <assemblyBinding>
    <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Http" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-4.5.0.0" newVersion="5.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      </assemblyBinding>
   </runtime>

   ...

</configuration>
```

Most likely you have to do this for a few more assemblies like webhosting, etc.

Comment: I edited the answer. For some reason DLL name was Castle Windsor changed to `System.Web.Http`.

Comment: You should never add binary redirects without making sure that the new assembly is binary compatible with the previous one.

Answer (score 18):

Or you could do this from NuGet Package Manager Console

```
 Install-Package Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi -Version 5.0.0
```

And then you will be able to add the reference to System.Web.Http.WebHost 5.0

Comment: work for me , just install Install-Package Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi

Answer (score 17):

When I installed Web Api 2.2 help this error started.  I added this to the web.config and it solved my problem.

```
  <dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Http" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" culture="neutral" />
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-5.2.2.0" newVersion="5.2.2.0" />
  </dependentAssembly>
```

Comment: Same here on a project that was Web Api 2.2 from the start, when publishing to Azure. The project worked fine locally, but on Azure I got the error from the OP. Adding these lines to web.config and republishing to Azure fixed it.

Answer (score 8):

The proper solution to resolve this issue is by following the steps

. Update Visual studio if you have older version to 15.5.4 (Optional)

2. Remove all binding redirects from web.config
3. Add this to the csproj file:

> ```
>  <PropertyGroup>
>   <AutoGenerateBindingRedirects>true</AutoGenerateBindingRedirects>
>   <GenerateBindingRedirectsOutputType>true</GenerateBindingRedirectsOutputType>
> </PropertyGroup>
> ```

4. Build.
5. In the bin folder, there should be a `(WebAppName).dll.config` file.
6. It should have redirects in it. Copy these to the web.config
7. Remove the above snipped from the csproj file again
8. It should work

**[`Detailed Blog`](http://sajeetharan.blogspot.com/2017/12/fix-could-not-load-file-or-assembly.html)**

Comment: it doesnt create all the bindings

Answer (score 4):

I simply set `Copy Local = true` on the missing assembly and that worked. This of course happens by right clicking on the missing reference (which is stated in the error message) and selecting properties; as below:

[image]

This should then solve one problem as there might be more than one assembly causing the issue - what I did is I selected all assemblies and right click on them; selected properties; and set them all to Copy Local = true; and then republish.

Comment: Worked perfectly. I only had to do "Copy Local = true" on System.Web.Http and System.Net.Http.Formatting

Answer (score 3):

For me it was only crashing with this error on a production environment, not on local machine; what solved it was to delete the content of /bin folder and then to regenerate it again.

Comment: This is something people should check. I was having the same issue. Turned out that there was an unnecessary dll for Microsoft.AspNet.Cors in the front end of my app. I had the bin folder deleted on the prod systems, republished the site, and magic.

Answer (score 2):

Just an obvious but possible helpful hint....remember to check that the new version you specify in your webconfig assembly binding is the same version that you reference in your project references. (ie as I write this...this would be 5.1.0.0 if you have recently done a NUGet on System.Web.Http

Answer (score 2):

```
<dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Http" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" culture="neutral" />
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-5.0.0.0" newVersion="5.0.0.0" />
</dependentAssembly>
<dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="System.Net.Http.Formatting" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" culture="neutral" />
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-5.0.0.0" newVersion="5.0.0.0" />
</dependentAssembly>
```

Answer (score 2):

```
 Installing NuGet package ASP.NET.MVC solved the issue for me. 
 To install package.
 - Right click on project 
 - Select "Manage NuGet Packages"
 - Select Online->Nuget.org from left menu
 - select "Microsoft ASP.NET MVC"
 - Click Install

 If you have already installed package earlier, please update the package by selecting Updates from left menu and then selecting "Microsoft ASP.NET" and click Update.
```

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2):

This might help someone.

I decided to go with MVC4 app.

***run project, worked***

Then Installed few packages like,
 **Microsoft ASP.NET WEB API 2.2 (4 packages)**

 
**Microsoft ASP.NET WEB API 2.2 Help Page**
**Microsoft ASP.NET WEB API 2.2 OWIN**

***run project, same error as mentioned in question***

**Solution:**

In ***web.config***

```
 <dependentAssembly>
      <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Http" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" culture="neutral" />
      <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-5.0.0.0" newVersion="5.2.3.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Net.Http.Formatting" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-5.0.0.0" newVersion="5.2.3.0" />
 </dependentAssembly>
```

**Problem Solved**

---

but then, some ***hotfix*** error found,
To resolve it,
go to ***VIEW*** folder of your MVC4 project,
find `second` ***web.config*** file and changed version from **2.0.0.0** to **3.0.0.0** as shown below.

---

```
<configSections>
    <sectionGroup name="system.web.webPages.razor" type="System.Web.WebPages.Razor.Configuration.RazorWebSectionGroup, System.Web.WebPages.Razor, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35">
      <section name="host" type="System.Web.WebPages.Razor.Configuration.HostSection, System.Web.WebPages.Razor, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" requirePermission="false" />
      <section name="pages" type="System.Web.WebPages.Razor.Configuration.RazorPagesSection, System.Web.WebPages.Razor, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" requirePermission="false" />
    </sectionGroup>
  </configSections>
```

---

Answer (score 2):

In my case, I was actually missing my `web.config` altogether, which had the appropriate binding redirects.  Restoring the `web.config` resolved the error.

Answer (score 2):

I could solve similar problem with System.Net.HTTP by adding assembly reference in app.config of main application.

```
  <runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Net.Http" publicKeyToken="b03f5f7f11d50a3a" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-4.1.1.1" newVersion="4.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly></runtime>
```

Answer (score 2):

I found that Deleting the BIN folder and then rebuilding the project fixed the issue without having to uninstall/reinstall packages.

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution ! Delete folder named package in project directory and then rebuild to run it.

Answer (score 1):

Me did not nothing, just copied development **Bin** folder **DLLs** to online deployed **Bin** folder and it worked fine for me.

Answer (score 1):

I got this issue when deploying to Azure using the Publish feature.
Remember to clear files at destination.

`Publish Settings -> File Publish Options drop down -> Check Remove additional files at destination`

This solved my issue, in case people have to hunt around for this like I did. Everything was the same version in my project/solution, just not at the destination I was deploying to.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem with System.Web.Http.WebHost, Version=5.2.6.0 being referenced but the latest NuGet package was 5.2.7.0.  I edited the web.config files, re-installed the NuGet package, then edited the visual studio project files for all of my projects to make sure no references to 5.2.6.0 persisted.  Even after all this, the problem persisted.

Then I looked in the bin folder for the project that was throwing the exception, where I found a DLL for one of my other projects that is not a dependency and should never have been there.  I deleted the offending DLL (which had been compiled using the 5.2.6.0 version of System.Web.Http.WebHost), rebuilt the troublesome project, and now it is working.

Answer (score 0):

As others have said just reinstall the MVC package to your web project using nuget, but be sure to add the MVC package to any projects depending on the web project, such as unit tests.  If you build each included project individually, you will see witch ones require the update.

Answer (score 0):

I had same problem and reinstalling package doesn't work.

My application runs in LocalIIS(not IIS EXPRESS).  I enable Assembly Load Trace and find out it want load *System.Web.Http* load from below temp catche. so **remove all catch folders** in it.

**C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files[my application]**

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem by reverting the changes that nuget had made to my `web.config` after running `nuget`. Revert the changes to a previous working version.

```
  <dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Mvc" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" culture="neutral" />
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-5.2.2.0" newVersion="5.2.2.0" />
  </dependentAssembly>
```

Answer (score 0):

What solved the problem for me was re-installing the **Microsoft ASP.NET Web API 2.2 Help Page** and Microsoft **ASP.NET Web API 2.2 OWIN** packages. I re-installed both at the same time, but I think it was the former that fixed the issue.

I tried the first few of the solutions offered here but that didn't help, then I compared my dependencies with the ones in a project that worked (from a course on Pluralsight) and the two dependencies above were a lower version (5.0.0) so I updated them to 5.2.3 and it started working.

Answer (score 0):

I had this from a WCF service. For me (as the issue was displaying in local dev), I simply had to delete the contents of the bin folder under the solution.  The the rebuild work fine once again.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue. Everything was working before. It's was originally made using Web Forms and later on added Web API for some things.

- Tried uninstalling, installing and reinstalling Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi package.
- Tried removing packages folder from solution and letting NuGet restore in VS.
- Tried removing individual assembly references (under References) and reinstalling packages.
- Tried adding binding redirects to 5.2.3.0 version in web.config mentioned in several answers. Nothing worked for me.

What worked was, in Visual Studio, change publish profile settings from Release to Debug. Strange, but that's what worked. So sharing here.

Answer (score 0):

If you **use several projects on a solution**, and call method in one project to another project, make sure that all projects (called project and caller project) **use the unique `'System.Net.Http'` version**.

Answer (score 0):

Change the Specfic version flag from true to false for the dll in the reference

Answer (score -1):

ASP.NET Version:4.0.30319.18408 belongs to .Net4.5 and System.Web.Http Version=4.0.0.0 is compatible for .NET4.0. So the versions that you have are not compatible. You should update you System.Web.Http to version 5.0.0.0, which is compatible with .Net4.5