# Could not load file or assembly System.Web.Http.WebHost after published to Azure web site

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio, azure, azure-web-app-service

I created a web project and it runs well in Visual studio. However, I got the following error after published it to azurewebsites. What can cause the issue?

> Could not load file or assembly 'System.Web.Http.WebHost,
>   Version=5.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' or
>   one of its dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition
>   does not match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT:
>   0x80131040)
>
> Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of
>   the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more
>   information about the error and where it originated in the code.
>
> Exception Details: System.IO.FileLoadException: Could not load file or
>   assembly 'System.Web.Http.WebHost, Version=5.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' or one of its dependencies. The
>   located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly
>   reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)
>
> Source Error:
>
> An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the
>   current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of
>   the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.
>
> Assembly Load Trace: The following information can be helpful to
>   determine why the assembly 'System.Web.Http.WebHost, Version=5.0.0.0,
>   Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' could not be loaded.
>
> WRN: Assembly binding logging is turned OFF. To enable assembly bind
>   failure logging, set the registry value
>   [HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Fusion!EnableLog] (DWORD) to 1. Note: There
>   is some performance penalty associated with assembly bind failure
>   logging. To turn this feature off, remove the registry value
>   [HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Fusion!EnableLog].

The following is part of web.config file.

```
  <system.web>
    <customErrors mode="Off"/>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5" />
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5" />
    <authentication mode="Forms">
      <forms loginUrl="~/Account/Login" timeout="2880" />
    </authentication>
    <pages>
      <namespaces>
        <add namespace="System.Web.Helpers" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Ajax" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Html" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Optimization" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Routing" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.WebPages" />
      </namespaces>
    </pages>
  </system.web>
  <system.webServer>
    <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false" />
  <handlers>
      <remove name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-ISAPI-4.0_32bit" />
      <remove name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-ISAPI-4.0_64bit" />
      <remove name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" />
      <add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-ISAPI-4.0_32bit" path="*." verb="GET,HEAD,POST,DEBUG,PUT,DELETE,PATCH,OPTIONS" modules="IsapiModule" scriptProcessor="%windir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\aspnet_isapi.dll" preCondition="classicMode,runtimeVersionv4.0,bitness32" responseBufferLimit="0" />
      <add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-ISAPI-4.0_64bit" path="*." verb="GET,HEAD,POST,DEBUG,PUT,DELETE,PATCH,OPTIONS" modules="IsapiModule" scriptProcessor="%windir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\aspnet_isapi.dll" preCondition="classicMode,runtimeVersionv4.0,bitness64" responseBufferLimit="0" />
      <add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" path="*." verb="GET,HEAD,POST,DEBUG,PUT,DELETE,PATCH,OPTIONS" type="System.Web.Handlers.TransferRequestHandler" preCondition="integratedMode,runtimeVersionv4.0" />
    </handlers></system.webServer>
  <runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="DotNetOpenAuth.Core" publicKeyToken="2780ccd10d57b246" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-4.0.0.0" newVersion="4.1.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="DotNetOpenAuth.AspNet" publicKeyToken="2780ccd10d57b246" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-4.0.0.0" newVersion="4.1.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Helpers" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-2.0.0.0" newVersion="2.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Mvc" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-4.0.0.0" newVersion="4.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.WebPages" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-2.0.0.0" newVersion="2.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="WebGrease" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-1.5.2.14234" newVersion="1.5.2.14234" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="EntityFramework" publicKeyToken="b77a5c561934e089" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-5.0.0.0" newVersion="5.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
    </assemblyBinding>
  </runtime>
```

Answer (score 131):

The `dll` is missing in the published (deployed environment). That is the reason why it is working in the local i.e. Visual Studio but not in the Azure Website Environment.

Just do `Copy Local = true` in the properties for the assembly(**System.Web.Http.WebHost**) and then do a redeploy, it should work fine.

If you get the similar error i.e. some other assembly missing, then make that assembly to copylocal=true and redeploy, repeat this iteratively - if you are unsure of its dependencies.

Comment: The `Copy Local` is already True. Strangely it shows the `Runtime Version` is v4.0.30319 instead of v5?

Comment: Do you know what happened here?  I had been running fine for 18 months when this jumped up and bit me.

Comment: I think a recent Windows update changed something. By me everything worked for years before starting giving the error today. Anyway setting Copy Local is a good solution for now. Eadel's answer didn't work for me.

Comment: This fixed the problem for me Thanks! But it seems strange to me that we have to include framework libraries in our projects(In my case not Azure but a IIS server). Does anybody know if its a case of running some updates so we dont have to include them anymore?

Comment: I haven't tried if this would succeed. Can you take a look at nuget to update the libraries. - nuget.org

Comment: @GlennGordon It's a hunch, but I think this happened to me because I installed .NET Framework 4.5 and ASP.Net 2…in a completely different project in VS Express 2013 (?!?). Then I went back to this older project, fixed a bug, and rebuilt and republished with VS2010. I think that this and 3 other DLLs I was missing (they didn't get built into my Release/bin folder on my workstation either!) are now in the GAC with .NET 4.5, or something like that, therefore the build system doesn't think they need to be included…but if you publish to a server without .NET 4.5, boom! Just a theory.

Comment: I created an "Empty MVC 4" project in Visual Studio 2013 and it seems these DLLs are set incorrectly so they don't get copied over.  Quite annoying.

Comment: Mini add-on since it took me forever to find copy local: In VS2013, you open up the "references" node in the project, and right-click->properties on the library you want to set "copy local" on.

Comment: If Copy Local is already set to true and you cannot update the WebApi because of dependencies, there is that trick to set Copy Local to false, build, then set Copy Local back to true and build.  I don't know why this works.

Comment: @DeeArgee I've fought this issue in several projects and always solved it but I never knew what the black magic combination of setting toggles, rebuilds and saves were. Your suggestion worked the first time I tried it. Thanks!

Comment: If it is still not working even after set the "CopyLocal=true" then other way around is to verify the dll version of all referenced assemblies which starts with System.Web.Http. Ideally all of them should be same, if any discrepancy found then refer the same assembly version for all of them.

Answer (score 94):

If you are still looking for an answer, try checking this [question thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19491860/could-not-load-file-or-assembly-system-web-http-4-0-0-after-update-from-2012-to).  It helped me resolve a similar problem.

edit:
The solution that helped me was to run `Update-Package Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi -reinstall` from the NugGet package manager, as suggested by Pathoschild.
I then had to delete my .suo file and restart VS, as suggested by Sergey Osypchuk in [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20859591/nuget-package-restore-failed-for-project-miscellaneous-files-value-cannot-be-nu).

Comment: Please avoid link only answers.. rather please post relevant information from above link here..

Comment: Running the Update-Package command resolved the issue, whereas none of the other suggestions worked. Thank you for the answer!

Comment: Best solution to the problem.

Comment: Perfect answer, Thanks !

Comment: I think in most cases, Naveen has the correct answer. However in my case, i pulled down our solution without the packages folder and when i did the nuget command to reinstall from packages.conf, it must have changed how the dlls were pulled. All other dlls were fine but this one in particular was pointing to the .net folder.

Comment: This solution worked for me also. I'm fairly sure this has been caused by ReSharper's 'Remove Unused Assemblies' functionality. Remove unused Assemblies sometimes blindly removes assemblies without check NuGet package contents.

Comment: Thank you so much! 2 days on this!

Comment: This is the right answer. And very important is to close VS and delete .suo file and then restart VS.

Comment: Make sure you have a backup/scc in place before running this. It removed all packages then failed for me, giving me a solution with no packages in package manager! However, restoring from git and then rebuilding to reinstate packages did solve the issue.

Answer (score 56):

I met the same problem and I resolved it by setting `CopyLocal` to true for the following libs:

```
System.Web.Http.dll
System.Web.Http.WebHost.dll
System.Net.Http.Formatting.dll
```

I must add that I use MVC4 and NET 4

Comment: thank you this was helpful. Do you know why these files wouldn't just be in GAC? Is it because different sites could be using different dotnet frameworks etc?

Comment: As I remember this issue has happened since Microsoft applied critical fixes  in that area (I guess in System.Web/ASP NET/MVC). I guess these namespaces are not in GAC (so not in native NET assemblies) but in separate Visual Studio or MVC paths.

Comment: This resolved the problem on my VPS (this is not only azure problem)

Comment: This worked for me (though I'm not using Azure). I was moving a project from a .net 4.5 framework environment down to a 4.0 one and got this issue at the end of everything.

Comment: Per DeeArgee's suggestion above, I already had LOCAL COPY = true for all 3 of these dll's.  But this suggestion finally solved the problem:
 
"If Copy Local is already set to true, there is that trick to set Copy Local to false, build, then set Copy Local back to true and build. I don't know why this works. – DeeArgee Nov 19 '15 at 17:16

Comment: This worked for my but I also had to add `Newtonsoft.Json` and `Localization`

Answer (score 34):

For me worked adding the following section to `web.config` file:

```
<configuration>
...
    <runtime>
    ...
        <dependentAssembly>
            <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Http.WebHost" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" culture="neutral" />
            <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-5.1.0.0" newVersion="5.1.0.0" />
        </dependentAssembly>
    ...
    </runtime>
...
</configuration>
```

This example stands for MVC 5.1. Hope it will help someone to resolve such issue.

Comment: Or just add `Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.WebHost` package via nuget.

Answer (score 17):

For me it started working after selecting "Remove additional files at destination" in File publish options under settings on the publish dialog.

Comment: This is the only solution here that worked for me. I guess there was some other old version of a dll there that tripped things up. Thanks!

Answer (score 10):

The dll is missing in the published (deployed environment). That is the reason why it is working in the local i.e. Visual Studio but not in the Azure Website Environment.

Just do Copy Local = true in the properties for the assembly(System.Web.Http.WebHost) and then do a redeploy, it should work fine.

Comment: same here, this is exactly what was needed.

Comment: Probably because its the same solution described in several other answers a year earlier.

Answer (score 6):

I'm using vs2012 and i think the update KB2781514 changed some setting. All my System.Web.Http in my MVC4 project changed to false and i keeping received this message. I had changed the `All file in this project` in publish property but its not working. Finally I have to change `Copy Local = true` one by one and solved this problem.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem in my Application.

```
System.web.http.webhost not found.
```

You just need to copy the `system.web.http.webhost` file from your main project which you run in Visual Studio and paste it into your published project `bin` directory.

After this it may show the same error but the directory name is changed it may be `system.web.http`. Follow same procedure as above. It will work after all the files are uploaded. This due to the nuget package in Visual Studio they download from the internet but on server it not able to download it.

You can find this file in your project `bin` directory.

Answer (score 2):

I got the same error and I changed my version from 4 to 3 and it is solved:

```
<assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
    <!-- Ensure correct version of MVC -->
    <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Mvc" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35"/>
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-3.0.0.0" newVersion="3.0.0.0"/>
    </dependentAssembly>
</assemblyBinding>
```

Answer (score 1):

This happened to me on VS2013(Update 5)/ASP.NET 4.5, under project type "Web Application" that includes MVC and Web API 2. Error happened right after creating the project and before adding any code. Adding the following configuration fix it for me. After resolving "System.Web.Helpers" issue two more similar errors surfaced for "System.Web.Mvc" and "System.Web.WebPages".

```
<runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Helpers" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-2.0.0.0" newVersion="2.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Mvc" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-5.0.0.0" newVersion="5.2.3.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.WebPages" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-3.0.0.0" newVersion="3.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
```

Answer (score 0):

I was missing several DLLs. Even if I manually copied them to the directory the next time I published they would disappear.  Each one was already set to Copy Locally in VS.
The fix for me was to set each one to Copy Locally false,  save, build then set each one to copy locally true.  This time when I published all of the DLLs published correctly. Strange

Answer (score 0):

If you have multiple projects in your solution and one of your projects fails to build because of this error then ensure you have installed the WebApi Core nuget package in that project. Simply adding a reference to the System.Web.Http does not help, you need to install the correct nuget package into that project.

I had multiple projects in my solution and WebApi Core was already installed in another project. I referenced the System.Web.Http assembly by right-clicking and ticking the assembly from the list and it did not work on Azure, though locally it would build okay. I had to remove the manual reference and add the WebApi Core nuget package to each project that needed the assembly reference.

Answer (score 0):

In the case if "Copy Local" is already True, I find it sometimes to work if you remove the files where it has been published to and publish again.

For example if you're using IIS, remove the websites and the contents of the directory to which they are published to, and publish again.

There might be older versions of files at the destination, so to ensure you aren't using older versions, delete everything before publishing again.

Answer (score 0):

I removed the following entry from web.config and it worked for me.

```
<dependentAssembly>
                <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Http.WebHost" culture="neutral" publicKeyToken="31BF3856AD364E35" />
                <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-65535.65535.65535.65535" newVersion="5.2.6.0" />
            </dependentAssembly>
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the package version is equal across the solution. I just downgraded & upgraded `Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc` package across the solution and the problem solved.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, this problem likely occurred after messing with nuget and getting it to reconcile versions.

I discovered that the system. Web.http.webhost versions were not the same in my development folder as in the deployed folder. All I did was delete the file, redeployed, and then it worked.

Mind you, I also set the reference to “copy local” as other people said here, but that didn’t work. I can’t say in the end if it was also a helping factor.