# Could not load file or assembly System.Web.Http

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have problem with mvc application, I use System.Web.Http for web api. When I publish application to server I get this error http://oi58.tinypic.com/2zpk3e9.jpg. I do not know what else to try, I added a reference from Assemblies normally, I tried to copy and add it, I tried to clean solutions. I ran out of ideas. Please consult anything.

Comment: Take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19491860/could-not-load-file-or-assembly-system-web-http-4-0-0-after-update-from-2012-to and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20323107/could-not-load-file-or-assembly-system-web-http-webhost-after-published-to-azure and some solutions mentioned there.

Answer (score 0):

Re install Web API from NuGet package, it will corrects broken dependencies. Open package manager console and run Update-Package Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi -reinstall. Good luck!