# Publish an ASP.NET-MVC in MS server 2003

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio, iis-7, publish

I made a WEB app using ASP.NET-MVC with a local SQL server database. I have a lot of issues while trying to publish it.

I want to publish the web app on a MS 2003 server. I have tried to do it with the Publish tool on Visual Studio 2012 but it doesn't work, I had this error : **ERROR_DESTINATION_NOT_REACHABLE**, I searched for some solutions on the internet and found this :

> Diagnosis - Web Management Service or Remote Agent is not installed or
>   unreachable on the remote computer. Resolution - Verify that Remote
>   Agent Service or Web Management Service are started on the remote
>   computer, depending on which one you are connecting to. You can do a
>   "net start wmsvc & net start msdepsvc" on the remote computer to
>   ensure these services are started. Also, ensure that a firewall is not
>   interrupting communications with the destination.

I have tried to install the **Remote agent service** on the MS server but it doesn't show up in the services lists.

I have also tried to publish the app locally using **IIS** (instead of running the app with the play button on VS studio), I have followed some steps in a forum and publish the package, I had this error :

[image: IIS Error]

My files are structured like that :

[image]

Can anyone help, I am really stuck on this and I can't move on !

On the server I have :

**Windows server 2003**

**IIS 6.0**

**SQL Express 2005**

On the development machine :

**Windows 7**

**Visual studio 2012**

**IIS 7.0**

**ASP.NET-MVC 4**

**Sql Server 2008**

Any help is needed, thanks.

Comment: "Cannot read configuration file due to insufficient permissions," sounds like you need to give the IIS user permission to the visTollWeb folder.

Comment: @Sully How can I set those permissions ? I have checked the visTollWeb folder and all the permissions are allowed

Comment: @Sully do you have an Idea ?

Comment: How about simplifying the equation a little, move the visTollWeb folder directly to D:\visTollWeb, and make sure Everyone has Allow all (note, adding Everyone perm is just for troubleshooting, will need to be removed).

Comment: @Sully thanks, I had this error : http://oi62.tinypic.com/2a7ubu1.jpg

Comment: @Sully, my files are structured like that : http://oi57.tinypic.com/1zr2cdd.jpg

Comment: Not sure if you ran through something like this yet, but sounds necessary to get MVC going on 2003 http://haacked.com/archive/2008/11/26/asp.net-mvc-on-iis-6-walkthrough.aspx/

Comment: @Sully Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/89784/discussion-between-abennouna-and-sully).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the solution thanks to this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20323107/could-not-load-file-or-assembly-system-web-http-webhost-after-published-to-azure).

I had some problems with the assemblies so I did Just do `Copy Local = true` in the properties for the assembly(**System.Web.Http.WebHost**) and then did a redeploy, it works fine.