# Azure HTTP Error 500.0 - MVC project

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio, azure, deployment

I make a new website + SQL DB on my Azure portal.
I create a new MVC 4 internet project in Visual Studio 2013 Express for Web.
I compile and it runs perfectly in local environment.
I set Azure to log detailed error messages.
I download publishing profile from Azure and deploy.
I get the 500.0 error (Module: AspNetInitializationExceptionModule).

The thing that makes it even more wierd is that a project I have developed on for a longer period of time is deployed without problems - only when making a new website + DB on Azure the problem arises.

Hope that somebody can give me a hint.

Answer (score 0):

Running this in Package Manager did the trick:
Update-Package Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi -reinstall

I got the hint from the following article after having read the eventlog:
[Could not load file or assembly 'System.Web.Http 4.0.0 after update from 2012 to 2013](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19491860/could-not-load-file-or-assembly-system-web-http-4-0-0-after-update-from-2012-to)