# Visual Studio C# WPF 'assembly with an incorrect format' Error

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio, asp.net-core

In my previously normal project, it suddenly started giving this error. There is no problem with the directory you mentioned. Even if I delete the .NET CORE SDK and reinstall it, the error persists.

> 1>SGEN : error : An attempt was made to load an assembly with an
> incorrect format: C:\Program
> Files\dotnet\packs\Microsoft.NETCore.App.Ref\**5.0.0**\ref\**net5.0**\Microsoft.CSharp.dll.

Comment: Your path says that assembly is .NET 5.  Are you still using .NET 4.x for your WPF application?

Comment: hi, check this link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49303108/build-error-an-attempt-was-made-to-load-an-assembly-with-an-incorrect-format

Comment: @RobertHarvey No, the target of my project is NET 5

Comment: how are you compiling?  AnyCPU, x86, 64 bit?

Comment: I have had times where I used a dll ref on a 32 bit app that was using a 64 bit compiled assembly.  i think you get that exact error message

Comment: actually it was a 64 bit solution that had a 32 bit dll in the /bin folder.