# .Net target framework changed to 4.7.2

Tags: asp.net, model-view-controller

I am facing below issue after updating .net target framework version to 4.7.2

> Could not load file or assembly 'System.Net.Http, Version=4.2.0.0,
>   Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' or one of its
>   dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.

Comment: May be you should upgrade it too for the latest version via nugget https://stackoverflow.com/a/46441411/3254405

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Strange issue with System.Net.Http 4.2.0.0 not found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47570912/strange-issue-with-system-net-http-4-2-0-0-not-found)