# Microsoft WebAPI asks for System.Net.Http, Version=4.0.0.0

Tags: c#, xml, asp.net-web-api, .net-4.8

Since I've updated my project to .net 4.8, I constantly get runtime errors (FileNotFoundException):

> Die Datei oder Assembly "System.Net.Http, Version=4.0.0.0,
>   Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" oder eine
>   Abhängigkeit davon wurde nicht gefunden. Das System kann die
>   angegebene Datei nicht finden.

The error is thrown by the following line:

```
WebApiConfig.Register(GlobalConfiguration.Configuration);
```

How can I fix that? I've already installed the latest System.Net.Http DLL version via NuGet and added a junction to the web.config:

```
<dependentAssembly>
  <assemblyIdentity name="System.Net.Http" publicKeyToken="b03f5f7f11d50a3a" culture="neutral" />
  <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-4.3.4.0" newVersion="4.3.4.0" />
</dependentAssembly>
```

This all did not help at all.

Comment: Did you do a clean build after modifying the config file? I think the version in the .proj file is wrong.  You may need to edit the proj file and correct.  To find  the correct version create a new simple project with Http defined.  Then open the .proj file in new project and compare the http version with old project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47923538/10406502) answer. My web.config file was full of redirections of obligatory files. I found, that all my other projects based on the used template don't have those redirects. Therefore, I used the method described in the linked answer to fix it.