# Assembly binding problems when upgrading to .NET Framework 4.8

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api

I need to upgrade my WebApi2 project from 4.7.1 to 4.8 so I did the following:

- Changed the `Target Framework` to 4.8 in the Properties tab
- Changed 'targetFramework="net471"' to '"targetFramework=net48"' in the `packages.config`
- Deleted bin and obj folders, and then did a `nuget restore`
- Checked that all referenced files under `References\Assemblies` point to the SDK `v4.8` folder
- Rebuilt the solution

Then I changed the following in `web.config`:

```
<system.web>
  <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.8"/>
  <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.8"/>
</system.web>
```

However I get an exception when running the project:

> Could not load file or assembly 'System.Net.Http, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.
>   Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.
>
> Exception Details: System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'System.Net.Http, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.

The corresponding section in `web.config` is:

```
  <dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="System.Net.Http" publicKeyToken="B03F5F7F11D50A3A" culture="neutral"/>
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-4.2.0.0" newVersion="4.2.0.0"/>
  </dependentAssembly>
```

The project is part of a larger solution and it references projects which target `netstandard2.0`. This is however not the problem, because everything was working when still using `4.7.1`

Where / what else do I need to check / change to make get the project going using `v4.8`?

Comment: Remove that binding `dependentAssembly` element entirely, you should not need it.

Comment: See also [Could not load file or assembly “System.Net.Http, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a”](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47923538/1260204), the 2nd answer in order of votes. This is a great way to recreate all the binding redirects and then copy them to your `web.config` file.

Answer (score 2):

Following the steps as per @Igor 's comment reference the [Could not load file or assembly “System.Net.Http, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a”](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38408167/could-not-load-file-or-assembly-system-net-http-version-4-0-0-0-culture-neutr/47923538#47923538) solves the problem.

Definitely the best solution.