# Azure Function: Could not load file or assembly Newtonsoft.Json

Tags: c#, azure, azure-functions

I'm aware that this issue is widely covered on the web and at stackoverflow but I could do with some extra help to sort this issue. I'm getting a runtime error relating to loading Newtonsoft, see below;

```
[11/07/2020 18:37:17] A ScriptHost error has occurred
[11/07/2020 18:37:17] Exception while executing function: Alerts. EmailSender: Could not load file or assembly 'Newtonsoft.Json, Version=12.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=30ad4fe6b2a6aeed' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified. mscorlib: Could not load file or assembly 'Newtonsoft.Json, Version=11.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=30ad4fe6b2a6aeed' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.
[11/07/2020 18:37:17] Exception while executing function: Alerts
[11/07/2020 18:37:17] Exception while executing function: Alerts. EmailSender: Could not load file or assembly 'Newtonsoft.Json, Version=12.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=30ad4fe6b2a6aeed' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified. mscorlib: Could not load file or assembly 'Newtonsoft.Json, Version=11.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=30ad4fe6b2a6aeed' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.
[11/07/2020 18:37:17] Function completed (Failure, Id=850be268-8e38-409d-aa59-fa071567779e, Duration=10672ms)
```

I have followed and implemented binding redirects as described [in this blog](https://www.thewissen.io/azure-functions-binding-redirects/). My azure function is a verion 1 function with .net472, im using Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Functions Version 1.0.36.

The exception occurs when a call to a referenced project is made, in that project there is a reference to Newtonsoft 10.0.2.

Any help is greatly appreciated - thanks!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38408167/could-not-load-file-or-assembly-system-net-http-version-4-0-0-0-culture-neutr/47923538#47923538

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll need to downgrade Newtonsoft to 9.0.1. You'd better read about the v1/v2 breaking changes and rewrite your function to .net core.

https://github.com/Azure/app-service-announcements/issues/129

Comment: Sorry, failed to mention the referenced project uses [Microsoft.Azure.Cosmos.Table](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Azure.Cosmos.Table) which contains a Newtonsoft.Json (>= 10.0.2) dependency.

Comment: you'd better rewrite and use .net core. Sorry but v1 is considered legacy and you'll face this dependency conflict. It worths to mention that old packages can contain performance / bugs. So it's highly recommended to use latest versions.

Comment: One of the reasons I was stuck on a V1 was due to the use of EF6. But I have done a little research and discovered that the latest version of EF6 works on .net core. Made the switch, works. Headache gone - thanks mate