# asp.net webforms throws Compilation Error at runtime

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms, .net-4.8

I have an asp.net webforms app using net48. the app builds successfully, but when I run it on IIS (debug mode) using vs2022 a compilation error is thrown.

## Server Error in '/' Application.

### *Compilation Error*

**Description:** An error occurred during the compilation of a resource required to service this request. Please review the following specific error details and modify your source code appropriately.

**Compiler Error Message:** CS0234: The type or namespace name 'Http' does not exist in the namespace 'System.Net' (are you missing an assembly reference?)

```
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Text;
using System.Web;
```

Detailed Compiler Output:

```
C:\Program Files\IIS Express&gt;...\bin\roslyn\csc.exe /t:library /utf8output /nostdlib+ /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\mscorlib.dll" /R:"C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Runtime\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\System.Runtime.dll" /R:"...\AppData\Local\Temp\Temporary ASP.NET Files\vs\fd4819ee\df02afe2\assembly\dl3\accdb94e\0029183d_ad2ad501\Microsoft.IdentityModel.Logging.dll" /R:"C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.ServiceModel.Activation\v4.0_4.0.0.0__31bf3856ad364e35\System.ServiceModel.Activation.dll" /R:"...\AppData\Local\Temp\Temporary ASP.NET Files\vs\fd4819ee\df02afe2\assembly\dl3\895e4e6e\0093f773_f42ad601\Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.dll" /R:"...\AppData\Local\Temp\Temporary ASP.NET Files\vs\fd4819ee\df02afe2\assembly\dl3\e3adb08e\00997024_7255d601\Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform.dll" /R:"...\AppData\Local\Temp\Temporary ASP.NET Files\vs\fd4819ee\df02afe2\assembly\dl3\cedbdf6a\003ec113_61bcd701\MailBee.NET.dll" /R:"C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_64\System.Web\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\System.Web.dll" /R:"C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\Microsoft.CSharp\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\Microsoft.CSharp.dll" /R:"C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.IdentityModel\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.IdentityModel.dll" /R:"...\AppData\Local\Temp\Temporary ASP.NET Files\vs\fd4819ee\df02afe2\assembly\dl3\eaebe8cd\00398ee0_458dce01\Microsoft.AspNet.FriendlyUrls.dll" /R:"...\AppData\Local\Temp\Temporary ASP.NET Files\vs\fd4819ee\df02afe2\assembly\dl3\04bcd556\005f960a_8c62d801\System.Memory.dll" /R:"...\AppData\Local\Temp\Temporary ASP.NET Files\vs\fd4819ee\df02afe2\assembly\dl3\be40d7fd\00a26521_13b7d801\HtmlAgilityPack.dll" /R:"...\AppData\Local\Temp\Temporary ASP.NET Files\vs\fd4819ee\df02afe2\assembly\dl3\986a1abc\00dcd6a3_37ecd301\System.Numerics.Vectors.dll" /R:"...\AppData\Local\Temp\Temporary ASP.NET Files\vs\fd4819ee\df02afe2\assembly\dl3\20e9fd64\00cbf555_befed401\Microsoft.Identity.Client.dll" /R:"...\AppData\Local\Temp\Temporary ASP.NET Files\vs\fd4819ee\df02afe2\assembly\dl3\758bc21e\00c21187_c604d301\Microsoft.Extensions.Options.dll" /R:"...\AppData\Local\Temp\Temporary ASP.NET Files\vs\fd4819ee\df02afe2\assembly\dl3\b20f8d49\014ff44d_a0c7d801\Common.Models.dll" /R:"C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Web.Services\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\System.Web.Services.dll" /R:"...\AppData\Local\Temp\Temporary ASP.NET Files\vs\fd4819ee\df02afe2\assembly\dl3\3b7ee7ba\00c21187_c604d301\Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.Abstractions.dll" /R:"...\AppData\Local\Temp\Temporary ASP.NET Files\vs\fd4819ee\df02afe2\assembly\dl3\61c16530\00c8a482_af2ed601\AjaxControlToolkit.dll" /R:"...\AppData\Local\Temp\Temporary ASP.NET Files\vs\fd4819ee\df02afe2\assembly\dl3\3806b253\00c2c330_48a6d601\System.Text.Encoding.CodePages.dll" /R:"...\AppData\Local\Temp\Temporary ASP.NET 
/R:"C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Core\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.Core.dll" /R:"C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Runtime.Serialization\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.Runtime.Serialization.dll" /R:"...\AppData\Local\Temp\Temporary ASP.NET Files\vs\fd4819ee\df02afe2\assembly\dl3\b5d6373a\0067c4dd_8f82d801\Serilog.Sinks.MSSqlServer.dll" /R:"C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.PageInspector.Loader\v4.0_1.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.PageInspector.Loader.dll" /R:"C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Web.Extensions\v4.0_4.0.0.0__31bf3856ad364e35\System.Web.Extensions.dll" /R:"C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations\v4.0_4.0.0.0__31bf3856ad364e35\System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.dll" /R:"...\AppData\Local\Temp\Temporary ASP.NET Files\vs\fd4819ee\df02afe2\assembly\dl3\c3d8b07e\009c16a6_05ded501\Microsoft.Azure.Services.AppAuthentication.dll" /R:"...\AppData\Local\Temp\Temporary ASP.NET Files\vs\fd4819ee\df02afe2\assembly\dl3\1e2ef47f\00566819_c664d801\Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb.dll" /R:"...\AppData\Local\Temp\Temporary ASP.NET Files\vs\fd4819ee\df02afe2\assembly\dl3\1dd28a39\00c21187_c604d301\Microsoft.Extensions.Options.ConfigurationExtensions.dll" /R:"...\AppData\Local\Temp\Temporary ASP.NET Files\vs\fd4819ee\df02afe2\assembly\dl3\4d792d32\008fe805_7a42d801\Google.Apis.dll" /R:"...\AppData\Local\Temp\Temporary ASP.NET Files\vs\fd4819ee\df02afe2\assembly\dl3\a1d6f624\008272c4_f5b2d801\MimeKit.dll" /R:"...\AppData\Local\Temp\Temporary ASP.NET Files\vs\fd4819ee\df02afe2\assembly\dl3\5dd7900b\00e7f2c7_50ecd301\System.Security.Principal.Windows.dll" /R:"...\AppData\Local\Temp\Temporary ASP.NET Files\vs\fd4819ee\df02afe2\assembly\dl3\66a8b0c5\0024a310_7a42d801\Google.Apis.Auth.PlatformServices.dll" /R:"...\AppData\Local\Temp\Temporary ASP.NET Files\vs\fd4819ee\df02afe2\assembly\dl3\65527fbc\00835eaa_b0d5d701\StarkbankEcdsa.dll" /R:"...\AppData\Local\Temp\Temporary ASP.NET Files\vs\fd4819ee\df02afe2\assembly\dl3\aafb540b\004fe523_99c1cd01\Owin.dll" /R:"...\AppData\Local\Temp\Temporary ASP.NET Files\vs\fd4819ee\df02afe2\assembly\dl3\1853d210\0049101b_726cd301\Serilog.dll" /R:"...\AppData\Local\Temp\Temporary ASP.NET Files\vs\fd4819ee\df02afe2\assembly\dl3\189b0330\000a2d1e_c664d801\Microsoft.Owin.Security.OpenIdConnect.dll" /R:"...\AppData\Local\Temp\Temporary ASP.NET Files\vs\fd4819ee\df02afe2\assembly\dl3\093b817b\008fe805_7a42d801\Google.Apis.Core.dll" /R:"...\AppData\Local\Temp\Temporary ASP.NET Files\vs\fd4819ee\df02afe2\assembly\dl3\43aaae07\00a8d72b_9fc7d701\Microsoft.Extensions.Primitives.dll" /R:"...\AppData\Local\Temp\Temporary ASP.NET Files\vs\fd4819ee\df02afe2\assembly\dl3\4a4e31ef\00f3f052_fbe6d501\System.Threading.Tasks.Extensions.dll" /R:"C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.ServiceModel\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.ServiceModel.dll" /R:"...\AppData\Local\Temp\Temporary ASP.NET Files\vs\fd4819ee\df02afe2\assembly\dl3\b012258d\004d157b_ad2ad501\Microsoft.IdentityModel.Protocols.dll" /R:"C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.WorkflowServices\v4.0_4.0.0.0__31bf3856ad364e35\System.WorkflowServices.dll" /R:"...\AppData\Local\Temp\Temporary ASP.NET Files\vs\fd4819ee\df02afe2\assembly\dl3\3df4c960\00947c0d_c664d801\Microsoft.Owin.dll" /R:"...\AppData\Local\Temp\Temporary ASP.NET Files\vs\fd4819ee\df02afe2\assembly\dl3\5ac1522e\0053b3e3_e8acd801\SendGrid.dll" /R:"...\AppData\Local\Temp\Temporary ASP.NET Files\vs\fd4819ee\df02afe2\assembly\dl3\0a415602\00da3d70_1e75d801\AngleSharp.dll" /R:"...\AppData\Local\Temp\Temporary ASP.NET Files\vs\fd4819ee\df02afe2\assembly\dl3\33ed2c6b\00c21187_c604d301\Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.dll" /R:"...\AppData\Local\Temp\Temporary ASP.NET Files\vs\fd4819ee\df02afe2\assembly\dl3\ad907327\00293718_c664d801\Microsoft.Owin.Security.dll" /R:"C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_64\System.Data\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.Data.dll" /R:"C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Data.DataSetExtensions\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.Data.DataSetExtensions.dll" /R:"...\AppData\Local\Temp\Temporary ASP.NET Files\vs\fd4819ee\df02afe2\assembly\dl3\96baf738\00af15fa_2eabd801\YoutubeExplode.dll" /R:"C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Xml.Linq\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.Xml.Linq.dll" /R:"...\AppData\Local\Temp\Temporary ASP.NET Files\vs\fd4819ee\df02afe2\assembly\dl3\a8c803f0\000cbfd9_571bd701\Newtonsoft.Json.dll" /R:"...\AppData\Local\Temp\Temporary ASP.NET Files\vs\fd4819ee\df02afe2\assembly\dl3\2bd164a7\007ae576_29c1d801\MailKit.dll" /R:"...\AppData\Local\Temp\Temporary ASP.NET Files\vs\fd4819ee\df02afe2\assembly\dl3\f4ef71f8\0036bab0_ad2ad501\Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens.dll" /R:"...\AppData\Local\Temp\Temporary ASP.NET Files\vs\fd4819ee\df02afe2\assembly\dl3\be73b18a\00dd8a2b_9ec7d701\System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Unsafe.dll" /R:"...\AppData\Local\Temp\Temporary ASP.NET Files\vs\fd4819ee\df02afe2\assembly\dl3\5969eb8d\005c4e80_dd70d501\System.Security.AccessControl.dll" /R:"C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.ValueTuple\v4.0_4.0.0.0__cc7b13ffcd2ddd51\System.ValueTuple.dll" /R:"...\AppData\Local\Temp\Temporary ASP.NET Files\vs\fd4819ee\df02afe2\assembly\dl3\0b6fef60\005543a0_37ecd301\System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.dll" /R:"...\AppData\Local\Temp\Temporary ASP.NET Files\vs\fd4819ee\df02afe2\assembly\dl3\d480652e\2a8baeaf_b2c7d801\xxx.dll" /R:"C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.dll" /R:"...\AppData\Local\Temp\Temporary ASP.NET Files\vs\fd4819ee\df02afe2\assembly\dl3\bd49ecea\001950f1_cbedd501\Serilog.Sinks.PeriodicBatching.dll" /R:"...\AppData\Local\Temp\Temporary ASP.NET Files\vs\fd4819ee\df02afe2\assembly\dl3\b67d5848\0057ced1_ac2ad501\System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt.dll" /R:"C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Configuration\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\System.Configuration.dll" /R:"...\AppData\Local\Temp\Temporary ASP.NET Files\vs\fd4819ee\df02afe2\assembly\dl3\e4e44e39\007eb42c_ae2ad501\Microsoft.IdentityModel.Protocols.OpenIdConnect.dll" /R:"...\AppData\Local\Temp\Temporary ASP.NET Files\vs\fd4819ee\df02afe2\assembly\dl3\c1cd338d\002425f9_ac2ad501\Microsoft.IdentityModel.JsonWebTokens.dll" /R:"C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Buffers\v4.0_4.0.3.0__cc7b13ffcd2ddd51\System.Buffers.dll" /R:"...\AppData\Local\Temp\Temporary ASP.NET Files\vs\fd4819ee\df02afe2\assembly\dl3\29391ecc\0005aa3c_747ad801\RestSharp.dll" /R:"...\AppData\Local\Temp\Temporary ASP.NET Files\vs\fd4819ee\df02afe2\assembly\dl3\3f384056\00865bf0_dfc4d701\BouncyCastle.Crypto.dll" /R:"...\AppData\Local\Temp\Temporary ASP.NET Files\vs\fd4819ee\df02afe2\assembly\dl3\0d614990\00375e1f_c664d801\Microsoft.Owin.Security.Cookies.dll" /R:"...\AppData\Local\Temp\Temporary ASP.NET Files\vs\fd4819ee\df02afe2\assembly\dl3\750b3cbb\00bc1907_7a42d801\Google.Apis.PlatformServices.dll" /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\mscorlib.dll" /R:"...\AppData\Local\Temp\Temporary ASP.NET Files\vs\fd4819ee\df02afe2\assembly\dl3\58485a22\00881b6d_9ec7d701\Microsoft.Bcl.AsyncInterfaces.dll" /R:"...\AppData\Local\Temp\Temporary ASP.NET Files\vs\fd4819ee\df02afe2\assembly\dl3\8d4fa25a\004e8e2b_736dd401\Serilog.Settings.AppSettings.dll" /R:"...\AppData\Local\Temp\Temporary ASP.NET Files\vs\fd4819ee\df02afe2\assembly\dl3\f3a1094d\00bc1907_7a42d801\Google.Apis.Auth.dll" /R:"...\AppData\Local\Temp\Temporary ASP.NET Files\vs\fd4819ee\df02afe2\assembly\dl3\72c739f9\00c21187_c604d301\Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Binder.dll" /R:"C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Web.DynamicData\v4.0_4.0.0.0__31bf3856ad364e35\System.Web.DynamicData.dll" /R:"C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_64\System.EnterpriseServices\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\System.EnterpriseServices.dll" /R:"C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Drawing\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\System.Drawing.dll" /R:"C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.ServiceModel.Web\v4.0_4.0.0.0__31bf3856ad364e35\System.ServiceModel.Web.dll" /R:"...\AppData\Local\Temp\Temporary ASP.NET Files\vs\fd4819ee\df02afe2\assembly\dl3\435724bd\000d09c2_bc52d501\Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory.dll" /R:"...\AppData\Local\Temp\Temporary ASP.NET Files\vs\fd4819ee\df02afe2\assembly\dl3\2706e763\0085da0c_136ad801\System.Text.Json.dll" /R:"C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.ServiceModel.Activities\v4.0_4.0.0.0__31bf3856ad364e35\System.ServiceModel.Activities.dll" /R:"...\AppData\Local\Temp\Temporary ASP.NET Files\vs\fd4819ee\df02afe2\assembly\dl3\ee2f1c2e\00c21187_c604d301\Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Abstractions.dll" /R:"...\AppData\Local\Temp\Temporary ASP.NET Files\vs\fd4819ee\df02afe2\assembly\dl3\3e8720d8\00c9eb4c_9ec7d701\System.Text.Encodings.Web.dll" /out:"...\AppData\Local\Temp\Temporary ASP.NET Files\vs\fd4819ee\df02afe2\App_Code.yl_1uw-m.dll" /D:DEBUG /debug+ /optimize- /warnaserror- /w:4 /nowarn:1659;1699;1701;612;618 /langversion:default /nowarn:1659;1699;1701  "...\AppData\Local\Temp\Temporary ASP.NET Files\vs\fd4819ee\df02afe2\App_Code.yl_1uw-m.0.cs" "...\AppData\Local\Temp\Temporary ASP.NET Files\vs\fd4819ee\df02afe2\App_Code.yl_1uw-m.1.cs" "...\AppData\Local\Temp\Temporary ASP.NET Files\vs\fd4819ee\df02afe2\App_Code.yl_1uw-m.2.cs" "...\AppData\Local\Temp\Temporary ASP.NET Files\vs\fd4819ee\df02afe2\App_Code.yl_1uw-m.3.cs"


Microsoft (R) Visual C# Compiler version 3.6.0-4.20269.4 (c94e3215)
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

D:\solution\App_Code\Class1.cs(7,18): error CS0234: The type or namespace name 'Http' does not exist in the namespace 'System.Net' (are you missing an assembly reference?)
\solution\App_Code\Class1.cs(293,53): warning CS0436: The type 'GoogleSearchAPI' in '...\AppData\Local\Temp\Temporary ASP.NET Files\vs\fd4819ee\df02afe2\App_Code.yl_1uw-m.0.cs' conflicts with the imported type 'GoogleSearchAPI' in 'TestProject, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'. Using the type defined in '...\AppData\Local\Temp\Temporary ASP.NET Files\vs\fd4819ee\df02afe2\App_Code.yl_1uw-m.0.cs'.
\solution\App_Code\Class.cs(350,52): warning CS0436: The type 'GoogleSearchAPI' in '...\AppData\Local\Temp\Temporary ASP.NET Files\vs\fd4819ee\df02afe2\App_Code.yl_1uw-m.0.cs' conflicts with the imported type 'GoogleSearchAPI' in 'TestProject, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'. Using the type defined in '...\AppData\Local\Temp\Temporary ASP.NET
```

Files\vs\fd4819ee\df02afe2\App_Code.yl_1uw-m.0.cs'.

There is a reference to System.Net.Http in the proeject

```
    <ItemGroup>
        <Reference Include="Microsoft.CSharp" />
        <Reference Include="System.ComponentModel.Composition" />
        <Reference Include="System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations" />
        ...
        <Reference Include="System.Net" />
        <Reference Include="System.Net.Http" />
        <Reference Include="System.Net.Http.WebRequest" />
        ...
    </ItemGroup>
```

In the .csproj file I have set the targetframework to 4.8

```
    <TargetFrameworkVersion>v4.8</TargetFrameworkVersion>
```

And removed all Imports of the roslyn compiler package `Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform`

Also, in the `Web.config` file I have set the compilation to target 4.8 and set the compiler

```
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.8"/>
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.8"/>
    ...
    <system.codedom>
            <compilers>
                <compiler language="c#;cs;csharp" extension=".cs" type="Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform.CSharpCodeProvider, Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform, Version=3.6.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" warningLevel="4" compilerOptions="/langversion:default /nowarn:1659;1699;1701" />
            </compilers>
        </system.codedom>
```

Note that if I remove the `system.codedom` tag from the Web.config, i still get the error with another version of the compiler:

```
    C:\Program Files\IIS Express> "C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\csc.exe" /t:library /utf8output /R:"...\AppData\Local\Temp\Temporary ASP.NET Files\vs\fd4819ee\df02afe2\assembly\dl3\accdb94e\0029183d_ad2ad501\Microsoft.IdentityModel.Logging.dll" /R:"C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.ServiceModel.Activation\v4.0_4.0.0.0__31bf3856ad364e35\System.ServiceModel.Activation.dll" /R:"...\AppData\Local\Temp\Temporary ASP.NET Files\vs\fd4819ee\df02afe2\assembly\dl3\895e4e6e\0093f773_f42ad601\Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.dll" /R:"...\AppData\Local\Temp\Temporary ASP.NET Files\vs\fd4819ee\df02afe2\assembly\dl3\e3adb08e\00997024_7255d601\Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform.dll" /R:"...\AppData\Local\Temp\Temporary ASP.NET Files\vs\fd4819ee\df02afe2\assembly\dl3\cedbdf6a\003ec113_61bcd701\MailBee.NET.dll" /R:"C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_64\System.Web\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\System.Web.dll" /R:"C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\Microsoft.CSharp\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\Microsoft.CSharp.dll" /R:"C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.IdentityModel\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.IdentityModel.dll" /R:"...\AppData\Local\Temp\Temporary ASP.NET Files\vs\fd4819ee\df02afe2\assembly\dl3\eaebe8cd\00398ee0_458dce01\Microsoft.AspNet.FriendlyUrls.dll" /R:"...\AppData\Local\Temp\Temporary ASP.NET Files\vs\fd4819ee\df02afe2\assembly\dl3\04bcd556\005f960a_8c62d801\System.Memory.dll" /R:"...\AppData\Local\Temp\Temporary ASP.NET Files\vs\fd4819ee\df02afe2\assembly\dl3\be40d7fd\00a26521_13b7d801\HtmlAgilityPack.dll" /R:"...\AppData\Local\Temp\Temporary ASP.NET Files\vs\fd4819ee\df02afe2\assembly\dl3\986a1abc\00dcd6a3_37ecd301\System.Numerics.Vectors.dll" /R:"...\AppData\Local\Temp\Temporary ASP.NET Files\vs\fd4819ee\df02afe2\assembly\dl3\20e9fd64\00cbf555_befed401\Microsoft.Identity.Client.dll" /R:"...\AppData\Local\Temp\Temporary ASP.NET Files\vs\fd4819ee\df02afe2\assembly\dl3\758bc21e\00c21187_c604d301\Microsoft.Extensions.Options.dll" /R:"...\AppData\Local\Temp\Temporary ASP.NET Files\vs\fd4819ee\df02afe2\assembly\dl3\b20f8d49\014ff44d_a0c7d801\Common.Models.dll" /R:"C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Web.Services\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\System.Web.Services.dll" /R:"...\AppData\Local\Temp\Temporary ASP.NET Files\vs\fd4819ee\df02afe2\assembly\dl3\3b7ee7ba\00c21187_c604d301\Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.Abstractions.dll" /R:"...\AppData\Local\Temp\Temporary ASP.NET Files\vs\fd4819ee\df02afe2\assembly\dl3\61c16530\00c8a482_af2ed601\AjaxControlToolkit.dll" /R:"...\AppData\Local\Temp\Temporary ASP.NET Files\vs\fd4819ee\df02afe2\assembly\dl3\3806b253\00c2c330_48a6d601\System.Text.Encoding.CodePages.dll" /R:"...\AppData\Local\Temp\Temporary ASP.NET Files\vs\fd4819ee\df02afe2\assembly\dl3\aa8e83f9\004775d2_c6dad701\DotNetZip.dll" /R:"C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Xml\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.Xml.dll" /R:"...\AppData\Local\Temp\Temporary ASP.NET Files\vs\fd4819ee\df02afe2\assembly\dl3\116e7994\00748389_ff9fd801\Google.Apis.YouTube.v3.dll" /R:"C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Activities\v4.0_4.0.0.0__31bf3856ad364e35\System.Activities.dll" /R:"...\AppData\Local\Temp\Temporary ASP.NET Files\vs\fd4819ee\df02afe2\assembly\dl3\c7e4f5a8\00bac1c6_50ecd301\System.Security.Permissions.dll" /R:"C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Web.ApplicationServices\v4.0_4.0.0.0__31bf3856ad364e35\System.Web.ApplicationServices.dll" /R:"C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Core\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.Core.dll" /R:"C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Runtime.Serialization\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.Runtime.Serialization.dll" /R:"...\AppData\Local\Temp\Temporary ASP.NET Files\vs\fd4819ee\df02afe2\assembly\dl3\b5d6373a\0067c4dd_8f82d801\Serilog.Sinks.MSSqlServer.dll" /R:"C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.PageInspector.Loader\v4.0_1.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.PageInspector.Loader.dll" /R:"C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Web.Extensions\v4.0_4.0.0.0__31bf3856ad364e35\System.Web.Extensions.dll" /R:"C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations\v4.0_4.0.0.0__31bf3856ad364e35\System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.dll" /R:"...\AppData\Local\Temp\Temporary ASP.NET Files\vs\fd4819ee\df02afe2\assembly\dl3\c3d8b07e\009c16a6_05ded501\Microsoft.Azure.Services.AppAuthentication.dll" /R:"...\AppData\Local\Temp\Temporary ASP.NET Files\vs\fd4819ee\df02afe2\assembly\dl3\1e2ef47f\00566819_c664d801\Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb.dll" /R:"...\AppData\Local\Temp\Temporary ASP.NET Files\vs\fd4819ee\df02afe2\assembly\dl3\1dd28a39\00c21187_c604d301\Microsoft.Extensions.Options.ConfigurationExtensions.dll" /R:"...\AppData\Local\Temp\Temporary ASP.NET Files\vs\fd4819ee\df02afe2\assembly\dl3\4d792d32\008fe805_7a42d801\Google.Apis.dll" /R:"...\AppData\Local\Temp\Temporary ASP.NET Files\vs\fd4819ee\df02afe2\assembly\dl3\a1d6f624\008272c4_f5b2d801\MimeKit.dll" /R:"...\AppData\Local\Temp\Temporary ASP.NET Files\vs\fd4819ee\df02afe2\assembly\dl3\5dd7900b\00e7f2c7_50ecd301\System.Security.Principal.Windows.dll" /R:"...\AppData\Local\Temp\Temporary ASP.NET Files\vs\fd4819ee\df02afe2\assembly\dl3\66a8b0c5\0024a310_7a42d801\Google.Apis.Auth.PlatformServices.dll" /R:"...\AppData\Local\Temp\Temporary ASP.NET Files\vs\fd4819ee\df02afe2\assembly\dl3\65527fbc\00835eaa_b0d5d701\StarkbankEcdsa.dll" /R:"...\AppData\Local\Temp\Temporary ASP.NET Files\vs\fd4819ee\df02afe2\assembly\dl3\aafb540b\004fe523_99c1cd01\Owin.dll" /R:"...\AppData\Local\Temp\Temporary ASP.NET Files\vs\fd4819ee\df02afe2\assembly\dl3\1853d210\0049101b_726cd301\Serilog.dll" /R:"...\AppData\Local\Temp\Temporary ASP.NET Files\vs\fd4819ee\df02afe2\assembly\dl3\189b0330\000a2d1e_c664d801\Microsoft.Owin.Security.OpenIdConnect.dll" /R:"...\AppData\Local\Temp\Temporary ASP.NET Files\vs\fd4819ee\df02afe2\assembly\dl3\093b817b\008fe805_7a42d801\Google.Apis.Core.dll" /R:"...\AppData\Local\Temp\Temporary ASP.NET Files\vs\fd4819ee\df02afe2\assembly\dl3\43aaae07\00a8d72b_9fc7d701\Microsoft.Extensions.Primitives.dll" /R:"...\AppData\Local\Temp\Temporary ASP.NET Files\vs\fd4819ee\df02afe2\assembly\dl3\4a4e31ef\00f3f052_fbe6d501\System.Threading.Tasks.Extensions.dll" /R:"C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.ServiceModel\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.ServiceModel.dll" /R:"...\AppData\Local\Temp\Temporary ASP.NET Files\vs\fd4819ee\df02afe2\assembly\dl3\b012258d\004d157b_ad2ad501\Microsoft.IdentityModel.Protocols.dll" /R:"C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.WorkflowServices\v4.0_4.0.0.0__31bf3856ad364e35\System.WorkflowServices.dll" /R:"...\AppData\Local\Temp\Temporary ASP.NET Files\vs\fd4819ee\df02afe2\assembly\dl3\3df4c960\00947c0d_c664d801\Microsoft.Owin.dll" /R:"...\AppData\Local\Temp\Temporary ASP.NET Files\vs\fd4819ee\df02afe2\assembly\dl3\5ac1522e\0053b3e3_e8acd801\SendGrid.dll" /R:"...\AppData\Local\Temp\Temporary ASP.NET Files\vs\fd4819ee\df02afe2\assembly\dl3\0a415602\00da3d70_1e75d801\AngleSharp.dll" /R:"...\AppData\Local\Temp\Temporary ASP.NET Files\vs\fd4819ee\df02afe2\assembly\dl3\33ed2c6b\00c21187_c604d301\Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.dll" /R:"...\AppData\Local\Temp\Temporary ASP.NET Files\vs\fd4819ee\df02afe2\assembly\dl3\ad907327\00293718_c664d801\Microsoft.Owin.Security.dll" /R:"C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_64\System.Data\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.Data.dll" /R:"C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Data.DataSetExtensions\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.Data.DataSetExtensions.dll" /R:"...\AppData\Local\Temp\Temporary ASP.NET Files\vs\fd4819ee\df02afe2\assembly\dl3\96baf738\00af15fa_2eabd801\YoutubeExplode.dll" /R:"C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Xml.Linq\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.Xml.Linq.dll" /R:"...\AppData\Local\Temp\Temporary ASP.NET Files\vs\fd4819ee\df02afe2\assembly\dl3\a8c803f0\000cbfd9_571bd701\Newtonsoft.Json.dll" /R:"...\AppData\Local\Temp\Temporary ASP.NET Files\vs\fd4819ee\df02afe2\assembly\dl3\2bd164a7\007ae576_29c1d801\MailKit.dll" /R:"...\AppData\Local\Temp\Temporary ASP.NET Files\vs\fd4819ee\df02afe2\assembly\dl3\f4ef71f8\0036bab0_ad2ad501\Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens.dll" /R:"...\AppData\Local\Temp\Temporary ASP.NET Files\vs\fd4819ee\df02afe2\assembly\dl3\be73b18a\00dd8a2b_9ec7d701\System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Unsafe.dll" /R:"...\AppData\Local\Temp\Temporary ASP.NET Files\vs\fd4819ee\df02afe2\assembly\dl3\5969eb8d\005c4e80_dd70d501\System.Security.AccessControl.dll" /R:"C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.ValueTuple\v4.0_4.0.0.0__cc7b13ffcd2ddd51\System.ValueTuple.dll" /R:"...\AppData\Local\Temp\Temporary ASP.NET Files\vs\fd4819ee\df02afe2\assembly\dl3\0b6fef60\005543a0_37ecd301\System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.dll" /R:"...\AppData\Local\Temp\Temporary ASP.NET Files\vs\fd4819ee\df02afe2\assembly\dl3\d480652e\d14f08ea_bdc7d801\xx.dll" ...
    
    
    Microsoft (R) Visual C# Compiler version 4.8.4084.0
    
    for C# 5
    Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.
    
    
    
    This compiler is provided as part of the Microsoft (R) .NET Framework, but only supports language versions up to C# 5, which is no longer the latest version. For compilers that support newer versions of the C# programming language, see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=533240
    
    warning CS1685: The predefined type 'System.ObsoleteAttribute' is defined in multiple assemblies in the global alias; using definition from 'c:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\mscorlib.dll'
    ...\APP_Code\KeywordsEVAPI.cs(7,18): error CS0234: The type or namespace name 'Http' does not exist in the namespace 'System.Net' (are you missing an assembly reference?)
    ...\APP_Code\KeywordsEVAPI.cs(293,53): warning CS0436: The type 'xx.GoogleSearchAPI' in '...\AppData\Local\Temp\Temporary ASP.NET Files\vs\fd4819ee\df02afe2\App_Code.ml7voh-s.0.cs' conflicts with the imported type 'xx.GoogleSearchAPI' in '...\AppData\Local\Temp\Temporary ASP.NET Files\vs\fd4819ee\df02afe2\assembly\dl3\d480652e\d14f08ea_bdc7d801\xx.DLL'. Using the type defined in '...\AppData\Local\Temp\Temporary ASP.NET Files\vs\fd4819ee\df02afe2\App_Code.ml7voh-s.0.cs'.
    ...\APP_Code\GoogleSearchAPI.cs(12,18): (Location of symbol related to previous warning)
    ...\AppData\Local\Temp\Temporary ASP.NET Files\vs\fd4819ee\df02afe2\assembly\dl3\d480652e\d14f08ea_bdc7d801\xx.DLL: (Location of symbol related to previous warning)
    ...\APP_Code\KeywordsEVAPI.cs(350,52): warning CS0436: The type 'xx.GoogleSearchAPI' in '...\AppData\Local\Temp\Temporary ASP.NET Files\vs\fd4819ee\df02afe2\App_Code.ml7voh-s.0.cs' conflicts with the imported type 'xx.GoogleSearchAPI' in '...\AppData\Local\Temp\Temporary ASP.NET Files\vs\fd4819ee\df02afe2\assembly\dl3\d480652e\d14f08ea_bdc7d801\xx.DLL'. Using the type defined in '...\AppData\Local\Temp\Temporary ASP.NET Files\vs\fd4819ee\df02afe2\App_Code.ml7voh-s.0.cs'.
    ...\APP_Code\GoogleSearchAPI.cs(12,18): (Location of symbol related to previous warning)
    ...\AppData\Local\Temp\Temporary ASP.NET Files\vs\fd4819ee\df02afe2\assembly\dl3\d480652e\d14f08ea_bdc7d801\xx.DLL: (Location of symbol related to previous warning)
```

Comment: Have you checked if all your libraries are supporting `.net4.8`? Also, you could look at your binding redirects and check the version of `System.Net.Http`  in your project/library and if they match. Also, it would be great to know, do you create an app from scratch or update the framework version of an existing project.

Comment: Maybe [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47923538/8978576) would be useful for you

Comment: @Serhii thanks for the suggestion. I tried what is mentioned in the answer you provided, but it didn't work. The generated redirects do not contain anyhting related to system.net.http. i dont know what that means. I tried to add one manually, and redirected  all versions to `4.2.0.0` but also this didn't work.

Comment: Also i tried to add `system.net.http` as a nuget package, but the dll never gets to the bin. i don't understand why.