# OwinStartup causes System.IO.FileLoadException

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, webforms

i have a asp.net webform app, which runs on 4.8 framework,
since i am new to signalR, i decided to make a seperate webapp which is a simple hub,
the webapp works and my console application connect's to it, everything is fine.

Here is Startup.cs

```
[assembly: OwinStartup(typeof(webapp.Startup))]

namespace webapp
{
    public class Startup
    {
        public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
        {
            app.MapSignalR();
        }
    }
}
```

here is the webconfig, when false the website launches, when true i get the error.

```
    <add key="owin:AutomaticAppStartup" value="true" />
```

### Here is the error...

### WRN: Comparing the assembly name resulted in the mismatch: Major Version
ERR: Failed to complete setup of assembly (hr = 0x80131040). Probing terminated.

[FileLoadException: Could not load file or assembly 'System.Runtime, Version=7.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' or one of its dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)]

[HttpException (0x80004005): Could not load file or assembly 'System.Runtime, Version=7.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' or one of its dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)]

---

System.Runtime.dll version is 4.8.9,

It appears that something is looking for System.Runtime, Version=7.0.0.0, but I cant see what, and the web app works perfect if i disable OwinStartup.

Comment: See following : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/migration-guide/versions-and-dependencies

Answer (score 0):

The solution from this post fixed it:

Recreated bindings, and now launches

[Could not load file or assembly "System.Net.Http, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38408167/could-not-load-file-or-assembly-system-net-http-version-4-0-0-0-culture-neutr)