# Missing assembly reference after WebApi call

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-web-api

I have WebApi controller which is working correctly and I can send requests using postman or anything else.

But when I send requests locally I get an error and when I'm trying to reach the endpoint I get an error:

> Could not load file or assembly 'System.Net.Http.Formatting' or one of its dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)

I've updated all the Nuget packages so all the projects have the same version.

I tried to delete package folder and restore all packages.

I tried to reinstal Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi for solution.

Nothing helped.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this,
[Stackoverflow Questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19491860/could-not-load-file-or-assembly-system-web-http-4-0-0-after-update-from-2012-to)

Run below command at NuGet Package manager to correct broken dependency

```
Update-Package Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi -reinstall
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are debugging the application in Visual Studio, try deleting *bin* and *obj* folders before starting up.

I had similar situation, though in my case the runtime exceptions were thrown on application startup.

Neither reinstallation nor restoration of NuGet packages would help me as well.