# Method not found on System.Web.Http when on Azure with .NET Standard 2 library

Tags: c#, asp.net, azure, asp.net-web-api2, .net-standard

I have an ASP.NET WebAPI 2 application on .net 4.7

I add a Microsoft.Azure.ServiceBus nuget which has dependencies on .NET Standart 
2.0

When I run my app locally on IIS Express inside VS2017 everything works fine.
When I deploy my app to Azure Web App I receive an error on any REST request

> Method not found: 'System.Web.Http.Controllers.HttpRequestContext System.Net.Http.HttpRequestMessageExtensions.GetRequestContext(System.Net.Http.HttpRequestMessage)'

As far as I understand there is different version of System.Web.Http on Azure web app and on my dev machine.

Why this happens and what should I do to fix this?

Comment: How did you deploy to Azure ? Did you try to reinstall the nuget `Update-Package Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi -reinstall` . (or) try to `copy file=true`  like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38186275/7073340)

Comment: I deploy through Publish command in VS2017. I tried the reinstall, no effect. I will try to set copy local, thx.

Comment: Hi @xakz, were you able to fix this issue ? I am also facing the same issue